# Why is my gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: method not getting called?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am creating a subclass of UIPageViewController for iOS 6:

```
#import "BGPageViewControllerWithoutTap.h"

@interface BGPageViewControllerWithoutTap ()

@end

@implementation BGPageViewControllerWithoutTap

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

I thought the `UIPageViewController` is the default delegate for all gesture recognizers. So I expect `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` to be called.

But it's not called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And where are you initializing the gesture recognizer?

Comment: It's the gesture recoqnizer that comes with UIPageViewController